# Will this be a correct way in using the Davis Putnam Procedure in Propositional Logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I can't really find much information about this topic, so it is difficult to know if I'm doing this right. Any feedback will be much appreciated. Thanks!

(¬P → Q) ∧ ((Q ∧ R) → S) ∧ ¬(¬(P → R)) ⊨ S

Convert to CNF:

(P v Q) ∧ (¬ (Q ∧ R) v S) ∧  (¬P v ¬R)

(P v Q) ∧ (¬Q v ¬R v S) ∧  (¬P v R)

Negation of Conclusion: ¬S

Convert F to clause form:
F = (P v Q) ∧ (¬Q v ¬R v S) ∧  (¬P v R) ∧ ¬S

≡ {{P, Q}, {¬Q, ¬R, S},  {¬P, R}, {¬S}}

Proof by David-Putnam procedure:

Set of Literals of F = {P, Q, R, S}

By P: New clauses using Resolution on P: {R}

```
      F = {{P, Q}, {¬Q, ¬R, S},  {¬P, R}, {¬S}, {R}}

      Discard all clauses with P or ¬P in them.

      F = {{¬Q, ¬R, S}, {¬S}, {R}}
```

By Q: New clauses using Resolution on Q: {¬R v S}

```
      F = {{P, Q}, {¬Q, ¬R, S},  {¬P, R}, {¬S}, {R}, {¬R v S}}

      Discard all clauses with Q or ¬Q in them.

      F = {{¬P, R}, {¬S}, {R}, {¬R v S}}
```

By R: New clauses using Resolution on R: {S}

```
      F = {{¬P, R}, {¬S}, {R}, {¬R v S}, {S}}

      Discard all clauses with R or ¬R in them.

      F = {{¬S}, {S}}
```

By S: New clauses using Resolution on S: { }

```
      F = {{¬S}, {S}, { }}

      Discard all clauses with S or ¬S in them.

      F = { }
```

Are output is the empty clause, so F is unsatisfiable, therefore the Claim is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See :

- Mordechai Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA114), Springer (3rd ed 2012), **Ch.6.2 Davis-Putnam Algorithm**, page 115:

> **Input**: A formula $F$ in clausal form.
>
> **Output**: Report that $F$ is satisfiable or unsatisfiable.
>
> Perform the following rules repeatedly, but the third rule is used only if the first two do not apply:
>
> > **Unit-literal rule**: If there is a unit clause $\{ l \}$, delete all clauses containing $l$ and delete all occurrences of $l^c$ from all other clauses.
> >
> > **Pure-literal rule**: If there is a pure literal $l$ [i.e. a literal $l$ that appears in at least one clause of $S$, but its complement $l^c$ does not appear in any clause of $S$], delete all clauses containing $l$.
> >
> > **Eliminate a variable by resolution**: Choose an atom $p$ and perform all possible resolutions on clauses that clash on $p$ and $\lnot p$. Add these resolvents to the set of clauses and then delete all clauses containing $p$ or $\lnot p$.
>
> Terminate the algorithm under the following conditions:
>
> > If empty clause $\square$ (or: $\{ \}$) is produced, report that the formula is unsatisfiable.
> >
> > If no more rules are applicable, report that the formula is satisfiable.

---

We have to apply it to the set $F_0$ of clauses:

> $F_0 = \{ \{ P, Q \}, \{ ¬Q, ¬R, S \}, \{ ¬P, R \}, \{¬S \} \}$.

1) Apply **Unit-literal rule** : delete $\{¬S \}$ and delete all occurences of $S$.

Result: $F_1 = \{ \{ P, Q \}, \{ ¬Q, ¬R, \}, \{ ¬P, R \} \}$.

2) Apply **Resolution** with $P$. Result: $F_2 = \{ \{ Q, R \}, \{ ¬Q, ¬R, \} \}$.

3) Apply **Resolution** with $Q$. Result: $F_3 = \{ \{ R, ¬R \} \}$.

No more rules are applicable, and thus the formula $F$ is *satisfiable*, i.e.:

> > $(¬P → Q) ∧ ((Q ∧ R) → S) ∧ ¬(¬(P → R)) \nvDash S$.

*Check*: with a valuation $v$ such that $v(S)=v(Q)=$ **f** and $v(P)=v(R)=$ **t**, the premise is **t** and the conlcusion is **f**.

Comment: So, for example if we get to the last literal, S, and our remaining clauses are {P} and {S}, then we will eliminate S. But, we will still have the {P}, so it is satisfiable.

Comment: @name - if we have only two clause : $\{ P \}$ and $\{ S \}$, they are clearly satisfiable. They are equiv to $P \land S$.